All closed subschemes of projective schemes (i.e. $X=\operatorname{Proj} A$) are projective (not necessarilly generated in degree 1)
$\newcommand{\Proj}{\operatorname{Proj}}\newcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}\newcommand{\O}{\mathscr{O}}$
So I asked a similar question here, but I have a different plan of attack this time, and I think it will work but I am confused about one step.
Let $A$ be a positively graded ring (i.e. $A=\bigoplus_{n\geq 0}A_n$), and $X=\Proj A/I$, and $f:Z\hookrightarrow X$ a closed immersion. I wish to show that $Z\cong \Proj A/I$. My first plan of attack was the following:


Fix an open cover of $X$ by projective distinguished opens $\{U_g\}$, and obtain ideals of $(A_g)_0$ (i.e. the $0$th degree subring of the graded ring $A_g$) via locally identifying $f$ as coming from the quotient map $(A_g)_0\rightarrow (A_g)_0/I_g$.
Using the ideals $\{I_g\}$ construct a homogenous ideal of $J$ of $A$.
Construct an isomorphism from $\Proj A/I$ to $Z$.


My new plan is this:

For all homogenous elements of $f$ set $U_f$ to be the distinguished projective open, and set $V_f=f^{-1}(U_f)=\Spec (A_f)_0/I_f$.
Using these ideals construct a homogenous ideal $I$ of $A$.
Show that $f(X)=V(I)\subset \Proj A$.
Show $V(I)$ is homeomorphic to $\Proj A/I$
Construct an isomorphism $\Proj A/I\rightarrow Z$.

I have done steps $1-4$. If $A_+^{\hom}$ denotes the homogenous elements of degree $1$ or greater for all $f\in A_+^{\hom}$ :
\begin{align}
J_f=\bigoplus_n\{a\in A_n:a^{\deg f}/f^n\in I_f\}
\end{align}
and set $I=\bigcap_{f\in A_+^{\hom}} J_f$. The main difference here is now I am running over all possible homogenous elements of positive degree in $f$ in order to make step $5$ easier.
Step 3 is an exercise in translating between open sets of $\Proj A$ and $\Spec (A_f)_0$, which I am confident in.
Step 4 is just sending $\mathfrak p\in V(I)$ to $\pi(\mathfrak p)$ and showing that this is a continuous open bijection, which I am again confident in, as I believe the proof does not differ very much at all from the affine case.
Now, for step 5, I set $F:\Proj A/I\rightarrow Z$ to be the composition of homeomorphisms $\Proj A/I\rightarrow V(I)\rightarrow Z$, and all that is left is to determine a sheaf isomorphism $F^\sharp:\O_Z\rightarrow \O_{\Proj A/I}$, and I believe this best done on a basis of affine opens. Since I have a ready made basis on $\Proj A/I$ given by the projective distinguished opens $U_{[f]}$, I get a new basis $V_{[f]}=F^{-1}(U_{[f]})$ of affine opens on $Z$ which by construction are equal to $\Spec (A_f)_0/I_f$. So I define my sheaf morphism on a basis by:
\begin{align}
F^\sharp_{V_{[f]}}:\O_Z(V_{[f]})=(A_f)_0/I_f&\longrightarrow \O_{\Proj A/I}(U_{[f]}=((A/I)_f)_0\\
[a^{\deg f}/f^d]&\longmapsto [a]^{\deg f}/[f]^d
\end{align}
which is well defined and I am pretty sure is an isomorphism.
To make sure this works, I need to check that this plays nicely with restriction maps. Let $U_{[h]}\subset U_{[f]}$, then there exists some $m$ such that $[h]^m=[f]\cdot [b]$ for some $[b]\in A/I$. I want to say the restrictions work out pretty much the same in the affine case, but keeping track of all the degrees is confusing me.
I guess my question is, is this the correct way of going about this proof? If so, how to I continue? I also think that the ideal $I_f\subset (A_f)_0$, should be the same as $\iota^{-1}(\langle \pi_f(I)\rangle)$ (here $\iota$ is the inclusion $(A_f)_0\rightarrow A_f$, and $\pi_f:A\rightarrow A_f$ is the localization) map but I can only get one inclusion, and that's the one that comes immediately. In the degree $1$ case, I believe this works out immediately, but for arbitrary degree it's proving trickier.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

It's worth saying that, with some definitions, your statement is completely tautological. Most define $X$ to be a projective $S$-scheme if there is a closed immersion $X\hookrightarrow\mathbb{P}^n_S$ (for some $n$) so that $X\to S$ factors as $X\hookrightarrow\mathbb{P}^n_S\overset{\text{canonical}}{\longrightarrow}S$. So certainly a closed subscheme of a projective scheme is projective. You might want to edit your title to avoid this false impression of your question (I clicked on this expecting a different thing...)

By the way, how do you know this is true? Skimming through Hartshorne, his proof (in the case of $A=A_0[u_0,\cdots,u_n]$) seems to fairly strongly rely on finite generation in degree $1$

@FShrike I guess the definition of a projective scheme I am using is one of the form $X=\operatorname{Proj} A$, for a positively graded ring $A$

@FShrike I thought this was true because in Vakil it’s an exercise and earlier in the chapter he says that we simplify things by looking at rings generated in degree $1$ but we don’t have to restrict to this…

I'm not completely convinced that, unless $f$ has degree one, $J_f$ is an ideal. So I'm not convinced $I$ is an ideal either. I might be missing something trivial. And about the "simplifications": sometimes results just aren't true without those "simplificiations". Sometimes, e.g., the Noetherian hypothesis is genuine. I know what you want is true in the instance of $A_1$ generating $A$ over $A_0$

@FShrike I think it is clear that $J_f$ is an abelian group. Let $a\in (J_f)_n$ be an arbitrary homogenous element (I think showing this on homogenous elements is fine since everything can be decomposed into a finite sum of said elements), and $r\in A_m$. Then $(ar)^{\deg f}/f^{mn}=(a^{\deg f}/f^n)\cdot (r^{\deg f}/f^m)\in I_f$, so $ar\in J_f$. This makes it an ideal no?

@FShrike perhaps in this case though I should take $J_f$ to be $\pi_f^{-1}(\sqrt{I_fA_f})$, as this is the general bijection between primes of $(A_f)_0$ and primes of $A$ missing $f$ when you don’t assume $A_1$ generates…

Say $a,b$ both have degree $n$, and both have (if $f$ is degree $m$) $a^m/f^n, b^m/f^n$ in $I_f$. Surely $(a^m+b^m)/f^n\in I_f$, but why is $(a+b)^m/f^n$ in $I_f$? I could argue it if $m=1$, but there are various seeming obstructions without that. $J_f$ is a direct sum of these graded pieces; you still need each graded piece to be an Abelian group (once zero is adjoined)

@FShrike, I see, completely failed to check that as I thought it be obvious. Thanks for the catch!

Your definition of $J_f$ is wrong - ditch the exponent on $a$ so that you get $a\in A_d$ such that $a/f^{\deg a /\deg f} \in I_f$ (you'll need to restrict to degrees that are multiples of $\deg f$ here, but that's fine). (I was writing an answer with more details based on your old post but then you edited, so now I have to change what I am writing, so if it shows up it will be later.) The overall statement you're trying to prove is true, and it's covered in Stacks somewhere (as per usual).

@KReiser would setting $J_f=\pi_f^{-1}(\sqrt{I_fA_f})$ work too or no?

Nope, that won't cover non-reduced subschemes correctly.

@KReiser is there some motivation for this or some construction that doesn’t explicitly rely on writing out the set? What if I dropped the radical?

Look, I've been busy, please wait for my answer instead of sending more comments my way. I'd much rather write a good answer than try and fit everything in the comments.

@KReiser Ok sorry, thank you for the help.

I think the best way to do this is to use the strategy of Stacks 0801, which proves a slightly more complicated claim by reducing it to the what you want: for $\renewcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}\renewcommand{\Proj}{\operatorname{Proj}} S$ a graded ring with irrelevant ideal $S_+$ finitely-generated up to radical (equivalently, $\Proj S$ quasi-compact by 01MD), and a closed subscheme $i:Z\to \Proj S = X$, then letting $I=\ker(S\to\bigoplus_d (i_*\mathcal{O}_Z)(d))$ we have that $Z\cong \operatorname{Proj}S/I$.
Define $Z'=\operatorname{Proj}S/I$. Pick homogeneous elements of positive degree $f_0,\cdots,f_n$ so that $\sqrt{(f_0,\cdots,f_n)} = S_+$. It suffices to show that $Z\cap D_+(f_i)= Z'\cap D_+(f_i)$ for all $f_i$. Since the ordering is arbitrary, we may as well prove this for $i=0$. Write $J\subset S_{(f_0)}$ for the ideal of $Z\cap D_+(f_0)$ and $J'\subset S_{(f_0)}$ for the ideal of $Z'\cap D_+(f_0)$; since closed subschemes of affine schemes are determined by their ideals, it suffices to show $J=J'$.
$J'\subset J$: define $d=\operatorname{lcm}(\deg(f_0),\cdots,\deg(f_n))$ so that $\mathcal{O}_X(kd)$ is invertible and trivialized by $f_i^{kd/\deg(f_i)}$ over $D_+(f_i)$, and for any quasicoherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ the multiplication maps $\mathcal{O}_X(kd)\otimes \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}(kd)$ are isomorphisms. We can see that $J'$ is the ideal generated by $g/f_0^e$ for $g$ homogeneous of degree $e$ in $\ker(S\to\bigoplus_d (i_*\mathcal{O}_Z)(d))$, and after replacing $g$ by $gf_0^l$, we may always assume $d$ divides $e$. But then $g$ vanishing as a section of $\mathcal{O}_X(e\deg f_0)|_Z$ means that $g/f_0^e$ is an element of $J$, and we've shown $J'\subset J$.
$J\subset J'$: Suppose $g/f_0^e\in J$. By the same trick of replacing $g$ by $gf_0^l$, we may again assume $d$ divides $e$. For any $0<i\leq n$, we have that $Z\cap D_+(f_i)$ is cut out by some ideal $J_i\subset S_{(f_i)}$, and we must have $JS_{(f_0f_i)} = J_iS_{(f_0f_i)}$. The RHS is the localization of $J_i$ with respect to $f_0^{\deg f_i}/f_i^{\deg f_0}$, so $f_0^{e_i}g/f_i^{(e_i+e)\deg f_0 / \deg f_i}\in J_i$ for some sufficiently large, sufficiently divisible $e_i$. So $f_0^{\max(e_i)}g$ is in $\ker(S\to\bigoplus_d (i_*\mathcal{O}_Z)(d))$ since its restriction to each of the $D_+(f_i)$ vanishes on $Z\cap D_+(f_i)$. So $g/f_0^e\in J'$, and we've shown $J\subset J'$. $\blacksquare$

Assorted commentary: your current strategy is a bit flawed, since $J_f$ is incorrectly defined (as per the comments - consider $k[x,y,z]/(x^2)$ for $x,y,z$ all of some common degee $d>1$) and you're kind of skipping over a lot of technology you should have here. Using affine opens instead of trying to do the gluing yourself is preferable, for instance.

I don’t recall assuming the irrelevant ideal is finitely generated. Is not true with out this condition? Also, how do we know what $(i_*\mathscr O_Z)(d)$ even is? Like why should we be able to construct this without first know that $Z$ is projective?


It is necessary to assume $X$ is quasi-compact, which is equivalent to $S_+$ finitely generated up to radical. It is not hard to construct a counterexample: just figure out a way to break the part where I did $f_0^{\max e_i}g$ by picking a sequence of $e_i$ that go off to infinity. 2. $(i_\mathcal{O}Z)(d)$ is the twist of $i\mathcal{O}_Z$ by $\mathcal{O}_X(d)$. The first thing you know because you know how to compute a pushforward of any sheaf for any morphism of schemes; the second thing you know because $X=\operatorname{Proj} X$ comes with $O(d)$, and then you can tensor.


I see so this does not hold for any graded ring $A$. Is there a way to rewrite this proof without appealing to the twist of $i_*\mathscr{O}_Z$? I ask because I’m trying to write this as an example in a set of notes before introducing $\mathscr O_X$ modules.

In my opinion, that's a strange thing to do, but sure, you can rephrase the proof. Pick $f_i$ as in the post, declare $J_{i,d} = {a\in A_d \mid a/f_i^k \in I(Z\cap D(x_i))}$ for $d$ divisible by $\deg f_i$ and $J_{i,d}=0$ otherwise. Then $J_i = \bigoplus_d J_{i,d}$ is a homogeneous ideal, and $J=\bigcap_i J_i$ is the kernel of the morphism I defined up in the post. The motivation here is that we're using the sheaf condition to figure out what the kernel is.

sorry for dragging this up again, but I have been thinkgin about this again, and I feel as though your proof only show that $f(Z)=V(J)$ where $J$ is the ideal you constructed in the previous comment. How do we conclude that this is isomorphic as a scheme to $\operatorname{Proj}A/J$?  In particular, I am still confused why $V(J)$ is only homeomorphic to $\operatorname{Proj}A/J$ when $A_+$ is finitely generated up to a radical

I'm afraid I don't understand the first part of your comment - in the post, I prove that the schemes $Z$ and $Z'$ are the same closed subscheme of $X$, and since $Z'$ is Proj of $A/\ker(...)$, there you go. The second part relies on being able to pick finitely many elements so you can take a max. I told you a general strategy to break that above - did you pursue it?

You set $Z’=V(\ker(\dots))$…how do we know this is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Proj}A/\ker$? I have pursued that, but I am still confused as to where things go wrong. It seems to me that any $V(I)$ should be homeomorphic to $\operatorname{Proj}A/I$ with no restrictions on $A$. This would mean the problem would have to lie in the sheaf on $Z$, like somehow there’s another scheme structure on $V(I)$  that makes it not projective…

Because that's what that means? If you have a different definition, I would encourage you to write the two definitions down, and then prove they're the same. Or at least you could write them down and someone else could explain why they're the same. 2: in the proof that $J\subset J'$, we need to take a max. Think about what happens if we can't do that: we'll have $J'\subset J$ but maybe not the reverse. I also see you posted a question about this recently.

I am sorry for the confusion; what is your definition of a projective scheme? Because to me a projective scheme is a scheme $X$ such that $X$ is of the form $\operatorname{Proj}A$ for a graded ring $A$. My definition of a $V(I)$ is the set of all homogenous prime ideals in $\operatorname{Proj}A$ such that $I\subset A$. As I have mentioned before, I believe (and have shown I think) that subspace $V(I)$ is very naturally homeomorphic to $\operatorname{Proj}A/I$, with not restriction on $I$. However, that is only the topological structure; I don't see how we get the scheme structure as well.

Yes I have posted a question about this, and someone provided a counter example here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/477445/counter-example-to-every-closed-subscheme-operatornameproj-a-is-of-the-form/477451?noredirect=1#comment1241928_477451 , which I am still working on wrapping my head around. Thank you for all the help I very much appreciate it and I am sorry for all the bother/annoyance.

Aha, okay, so I think we just had a difference in terminology and I was potentially being a little imprecise. I've edited slightly to try and be clearer. Does that help?

It does, but I am still confused I think. My apologies. So far what I think you have done is shown that $Z=Z’$ because the ideals which cut out these closed sets are equal. Now $Z’$ is naturally homeomorphic to $\operatorname{Proj}A/J$, so we can put that scheme structure on it. Does the sheaf isomorphism between the sheaves of rings on $Z’$ and $Z$ then just come from the one defining the closed embedding somehow? And it’s an isomorphism because these ideals are equal?

I defined $Z'=\operatorname{Proj} S/I$. I showed that on every affine open of the form $D_+(f)\subset\operatorname{Proj} S$ for $f$ homog. of pos. deg., we have $\mathcal{I}Z(D+(f))=\mathcal{I}{Z'}(D+(f))$, and this gives that the two schemes $Z$ and $Z'$ are isomorphic: a closed immersion is uniquely determined by its sheaf of ideals, and the above condition is enough to prove the sheaves of ideals are the same since the $D_+(f)$ form a basis for the topology on $X$ and it's enough to specify a sheaf on a basis. If you have further questions about these facts, I would recommend new posts.

thank you for all the help I have figured out what is meant by this argument now.
